# Error 1004 in sum loop with dynamic boundaries (also ... slow)

Tags: vba, sum

I am new to VBA and sitting with a sum, which includes three if loops. The code looks like this

```
Dim strKonto As String
Dim str?r As String
Dim strUdbetaling As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim yearkbottom As Integer
Dim yearktop As Integer


For i = 1 To 50 'wsRefor.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 1 To 20 '200
        yearkbottom = (wsRefor.Cells(k + 3, 1) - 2007) + 1
        yearktop = (yearkbottom - 2007) + 4000

        For j = yearkbottom To yearktop

            strKonto = Right(wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 2), 4)
            str?r = wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 1)
            strUdbetaling = Left(wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 2), 1)
            counter = Val(str?r) - 2007

            If wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, 2) = strKonto Then
                If wsRefor.Cells(1, k + 3) = str?r Then
                    If strUdbetaling = 2 Then
                        wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, k + 3) = wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, k + 3) + wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, k + 2 - counter * 12)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next k
Next i
```

For the j-loop I tried to make the boundaries dynamic to make the calculations a little slower. That is, I am sure all values which the j loop finds are not spread over the entire range of j, but rather within the range defined above using k.

However, when I make this alteration I get an 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

Anyone able to spot the mistake, or alternatively to suggest any methods of speeding up the sum?

Best,

ID

EDIT: I found out what the problem was. The j counter took on zero at some point in the new boundaries, and when that happens (or when it is negative) the mistake I got comes up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: At what line of code you are getting this error?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. I am pretty sure it comes at either of the three lines that starts with 
     yearkbottom = (wsRefor.Cells(k + 3, 1) - 2007) + 1

and ends with

    For j = yearkbottom To yearktop

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- After the error is shown, a line should be marked with a yellow bar. This is the error line.

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa  you have `Dim str?r As String` , my VB editor "screams" when it saw the **str?r** , is that a type error ?

Comment: @ShaiRado , that is just non-English letters, so don't worry about that. I checked the code and it runs fine if I comment out the three lines I mentioned and inserts 1 to 1000 instead for the j boundaries.

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa Debug the Code as suggested by Andre. I Ran the Code you gave with some sample data. I see it is working fine. So i guess there is some thing wrong with your input data which is coming from 'wsRefor'

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa, Please see that whenever j value is turning to 0 or negative value, this loop is throwing the error you specified

Comment: Thanks for that. I realized why it was zero, because I had made a mistake in the cells formula in the first of three lines. Thanks @Siva. That is so nice of you :-)

Comment: Always Welcome!!! All the Best!!!

Comment: @Siva. I fixed the code now, and don't get the problem any more. So thanks. However(!), now VBA stop responding, every time I run the code.

i loops through ~50 obs
k loops through ~140 obs
j loops through ~4000 obs

Is the set simply to large? Same happens if I write all the i,j,k boundaries in hard-coded number, so the dynamicism is not the problem.

Comment: Possibly due the loops. Your code have to perform 50*140*4000 iterations. Every time it iterates its is interacting with excel sheets. So possible these could be some of the reasons. Please find this link and see if its helping you else, lets see if you can try something else. https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there could be something about the setting the data into arrays. However, I have zero experience putting data into arrays. Do you know how to do it, or know a guide to do it?

Comment: I will try it from my end and will share the code.Mean while you can search  for arrays in vba and their usage

Comment: @Siva Cool. Thanks. I did look a little bit into it before and tried to make the j designated column into an array (still dynamic for each k as in the code above). However, I can't get the code to run. I guess I don't know how to make a range properly. Tried to do something like 

`(Range((yearkbottom, k + 2 - counter * 12),(yearktop, k + 2 - counter * 12))` 

but I get an error message

Comment: Added one more solution by fine tuning some of the areas.Hope it you help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try below one. I have tried to do some fine tuning.

```
Dim strKonto As String
Dim strr As String
Dim strUdbetaling As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim yearkbottom As Integer
Dim yearktop As Integer

Dim arryearkbottom(20) 'Declaring a Static Array of Size 21,(Starts from 0 index)
Dim arryearktop(20) 'Declaring a Static Array of Size 21,(Starts from 0 index)

'Initial Values
screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating

statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar

calcState = Application.Calculation

eventsState = Application.EnableEvents

'Turning off the values for performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False

'Reading all the values from sheet to Arrays
For i = 1 To 20
    arryearkbottom(i) = (wsRefor.Cells(i + 3, 1) - 2007) + 1
    arryearktop(i) = (arryearkbottom(i) - 2007) + 4000

Next


For i = 1 To 50 'wsRefor.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 1 To 20 '200
        'yearkbottom = (wsRefor.Cells(k + 3, 1) - 2007) + 1
        'yearktop = (yearkbottom - 2007) + 4000
         For j = arryearkbottom(k) To arryearktop(k)

            strKonto = Right(wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 2), 4)
            strr = wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 1)
            strUdbetaling = Left(wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, 2), 1)
            counter = Val(strr) - 2007

            If wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, 2) = strKonto Then
                If wsRefor.Cells(1, k + 3) = strr Then
                    If strUdbetaling = 2 Then
                        wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, k + 3) = wsRefor.Cells(i + 1, k + 3) + wsArk7.Cells(j + 4, k + 2 - counter * 12)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next k
Next i


'Setting to Initial values
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState

Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState

Application.Calculation = calcState

Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
```

Solution2:

```
Dim strKonto As String
Dim strr As String
Dim strUdbetaling As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim yearkbottom As Integer
Dim yearktop As Integer
Dim rngwsRefor As Range
Dim rngwsArk7 As Range

'Initial Values
screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating
statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar
calcState = Application.Calculation
eventsState = Application.EnableEvents

'Turning off the values for performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Reading Entire sheet values to range
Set rngwsRefor = wsRefor.Cells
Set rngwsArk7 = wsArk7.Cells


For i = 1 To 50 'wsRefor.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 1 To 20 '200
        yearkbottom = (rngwsRefor(k + 3, 1).Value - 2007) + 1
        yearktop = (yearkbottom - 2007) + 4000
         For j = yearkbottom To yearktop

            strKonto = Right(rngwsArk7(j + 4, 2).Value, 4)
            strr = rngwsArk7(j + 4, 1).Value
            strUdbetaling = Left(rngwsArk7(j + 4, 2).Value, 1)
            counter = Val(strr) - 2007

            If rngwsRefor(i + 1, 2).Value = strKonto Then
                If rngwsRefor(1, k + 3).Value = strr Then
                    If strUdbetaling = 2 Then
                        rngwsRefor(i + 1, k + 3).Value = rngwsRefor(i + 1, k + 3).Value + rngwsArk7.Cells(j + 4, k + 2 - counter * 12).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next k
Next i


'Setting to Initial values
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
```